# debug_traceBlockByHash regenerates historical state and increases memory usage

Tags: go-ethereum, transaction-trace

Question.

- I often get logs like the following. I assume this is being called from outside, but why is it being called? Also, is the error because my node does not have historical state up to (latest block - 128) blocks high? (I read this thread: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/26636)

```
Served debug_traceBlockByHash            conn=10.11.1.70:59004 reqid=1  duration=9.13638ms    err="required historical state unavailable (reexec=128)"
```

- Next, I got the following logs and OOM with increased memory usage. Does this mean that debug_traceBlockByHash has successfully started and is rebuilding the historical state for trace? Is it common for memory usage to increase with this call?

```
Apr  1 20:51:05 geth: INFO [04-01|20:51:05.181] Regenerating historical state            block=16,903,288 target=16,903,375 remaining=87  elapsed=14.025860405s
```

- If the increase in memory usage due to debug_traceBlockByHash is common, is there any countermeasure?